# Get Facebook User Profile ID instead of App-Scoped user id in Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

I have 6 different applications on FB which have one database with users. All of them was created long time ago, on V1.0 and I have several hundred thousands registered users. People are buying daily tickets for those games, and tickets are valid for any of games. And that works just fine.

But since V2.0 for each application I'm getting different app_scoped user ID which are different to original ID in database, so I'm getting all of them as a new users every time they change the game so purchased ticket (which is app for registering) will not be available for user in any of app caused by totally different ID's... Note that many of them don't want to leave email, so email cannot be used as parameter for user identification.

I have read about finding original user ID with API V2.x calls, but still I'm unsuccessful. Any idea of getting real user ID with V2.x API calls?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can´t get the real IDs in new Apps anymore, it would make the whole concept of App Scoped IDs void. But you can map the IDs of different Apps with the Business Mapping API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business